# How to query the progress or estimation of Index Rebuild

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2016

I get SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU2) and partition table (2 TB space, like 10 billion records, avarage 250M records per one partiton month) with non-unique and non-clustered index and run enable (rebuild) with typical command:

```
ALTER INDEX [IX_name_Partition] ON [dbo].[TBL_name_Partition] REBUILD PARTITION = ALL
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) 
GO
```

It's running for 12 hours and who knows how long it can run at all.
Any ideas how to get an estimate/progress for its operation?

The most popular threads related it topics (scripts that I tried but unfortunately it doesn't help at all):

- [How to query the progress of SQL Reindex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/94444/how-to-query-the-progress-of-sql-reindex.html)
- [Check progress of alter index reorganize / rebuild](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76375/check-progress-of-alter-index-reorganize-rebuild/76379)

**UPD!** P.S. After 19 hours this rebuild was completed successfully.

Comment: There is no way to estimate the progress of rebuild, but if your partitioning is made by date, or by other ever increasing column, you probably don't need to rebuild ALL the partitions, only the last one. In any case, why don't you rebuild 1 partition at a time to estimate how long it takes, to extend this time to remainig partitions?

Comment: How big is your table? I mean Gb, not the number of records. 12 hours seems to be exagerated, but if your table is about 400Gb and your server has only 4Gb of RAM it is possible

Comment: @sepupic, thanks for the question, updated size and real row count of table.
About the index, it was disabled, unfortunately, I can't rebuild only one partition for the disabled index.

Comment: I don't know how big was your index ( I hope it was much smaller than your table) but 2Tb is really big size, I think you should check the autogrowth size of your data file and of your log. I think your server now spends a lot of time for expand your db, and log in particular.

Comment: Maybe I should explain...To rebuild an index means to create anew one, then drop the old one. Your new index will have the size non less than the size of disabled index. So your db need to have: data space to accomodate your new index, data space to make a sort since you used SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, and it needs log to be large enough to accomodate this enormous transaction

Comment: So, assuming that your db recovery model is full and index size is 500Gb, your db need to have additional 2Tb size and at least 1Tb of log. If you autogrowth size is small, for exampe 100Mb, how many time your data file and log size need to expand? And your log should be also zero initialized. So, to speed up you rebuild, you should grow your data file and log size in bigger chunks BEFORE the rebuild. You can helpyour server even now, by estimating the size it needs and adding it in a big chunks

Comment: @sepupiс, thanks for the idea for future operations, cause my autogrowth setting was set to 1024 MB, probably I can extend them to 51200 MB before next time.

Comment: ...But only for data file. For log file it's recommended to make it grow in smaller chunks to not create to large VLFs. But it's always better if you do it before the operation than it does your server during the operation. If your rebuild is still working contol the session's waits in sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks  join sys.dm_exec_sessions, it will show you what server is doing now and for what it's waiting for